# add clicked link to input field

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink

I have created a fiddle here:

http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/paPRg/1/

Basically, I want to allow users to hover over a link, panel appears and they can click a link on that panel, which gets added to the input field.

Furthermore, I really need to make the LINKS dynamic.

Wonder if anyone knows :

1. onclick the link url is placed unto the text field.
2. if they click OWN LINK , it closes panel and focuses in the input field.
3. how to make this dynamic, so if we wanted 2 or more of these on one page.. how would I make the script dynamic so it didnt mean a whole lot of repetitive javascript.

currently the link id is id="demo-basic"

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a handler like this to your function (see http://jsfiddle.net/7QTXU/).  This is heavily dependent on the structure of your document to find the appropriate form field to fill in, but if you want multiple ones with only a single handler, I think you'll have to depend on the DOM structure to locate them.  If you could simplify the relationship, that would help, for example, if the form filed were to immediately follow the preview, you could  use `next` rather than having to traverse up to a parent node, then find the element.  There may be a method on `hovercard` to close it using its API, but `hide` seems to work and not interfere with the operation of the plugin.  Also, the check depends on the value of the href to see which one should close the hovercard.  It would be better if it had a class that could be used rather than have to match on the href.

```
$('.hc-details a').live('click', function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if (!$this.attr('href').match(/^javascript/)) {
        $this.closest('p')
             .nextAll('form:first')
             .find('input:text')
             .val($this.attr('href'));
    }
    $this.closest('.hc-details').hide();
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Ahh that is elegant ! Absolutely, sweet. Could I ask one more favour please @tvanfosson , if I had 2 or more of these hover links on a page, how I would separately ID these, so as not to duplicate and triplicate the js. Im really bad with JS. I am hoping, to pull the link panels in via ajax.

Comment: @422 the code I gave you uses a live handler and should work with dynamically added links as long as they are contained in an element with the `hc-details` class.  The code is dependent on classes and document structure, not ids and should apply as long as you have the relative structure the same.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like this

```
$('#links li').click(function(e){
    var a = $(this).html();
    $('input').val(a);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/paPRg/7/

This places the link element (HTML and all) inside the input.

If you just wanted the link name, then do this

```
$('#links li a').click(function(e){
    var a = $(this).html();
    $('input').val(a);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Example 2:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/paPRg/11/

**EDIT**

As per @RobW's comment

> The OP wants to store the link, not the HTML.

Then do this

```
$('#links li a').click(function(e){
    var a = $(this).attr('href');
    $('input').val(a);
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Example 3:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/paPRg/12/

**EDIT 2**

Here is the script you can use for detecting their own link.  Don't know how to use that `.hoverCard` function.

```
$('#links li a').click(function(e){
    var a = $(this).attr('href');
    var b = $(this).text();
    if(b == 'Own Link'){
        $('input').focus();
        //close hover with .hoverCard()
    }
    else{
        $('input').val(a).focus();
    }    
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

**Example 4:** http://jsfiddle.net/jasongennaro/paPRg/14/

Comment: Actually, the links each have a same domain ID. So the link would be in the panel <a href="somedomain.com/p/64763764374"> so all we need is the ID passing. Which is no biggy. Closing the panel seems to be the biggest problem, which is a pain. Also onclick of OWN LINK, it would be nice to focus in the input element. But on the whole this is ideal. Only gripe I have is, how I would make this more dynamic. Any pointers? http://jsfiddle.net/ozzy/paPRg/1/

Comment: @422 The last bit of code will do the `focus` on the `input`.  Not sure what you mean by more dynamic?

Comment: @jason, ahhh your bloody good. So really after a combination of your demo 4 code, and tvanfosson's code. By dynamic I mean, if you look at my fiddle in comment above yours ^ you will see because the links, share same ID, only one appears, so need a method of allowing multiple hovers for links ( for various posts ) on a page, that each have their OWN content. As we will be pulling this in via ajax.

Answer (score 1):

Updated your fiddle to add the urls to the input on click:

http://jsfiddle.net/GolezTrol/JuVxh/3/

It sets the focus too, but I don't know how to nicely hide the panel. I don't know this hovercard function.